# Creating new lists from values out of lists and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

So I have an array of values in which I would like to take out only certain ones to put in a new list or array. To better explain, here is an example of what I'm getting at.

Say I have this array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>
```

From this array I would want 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, and 8 in a new list or array.
No matter the range of the array, I always want the 1st, next to last, and every two between them. Does anyone have a good way to do this?

So I guess if I explain why I need these values in such a specific way it might help in the solutions. The array I have in my code is a series angles I calculated in previous steps. However, I don't need all the values for the next part of my program.

So far my best guess has been to try and make a dictionary that might assign the values to the angle names I'm looking for.

Something like this...

```
angle_name = { i=f, i+1=s, i+2=o}
if angle_name.haskey(x[i]):
    somenewlist.append(angle_name[x[i]])
```

Does that make any sense?
My end goal is to eventually pick out the desired angles, name them appropriately and organize them in to a nice looking output.

Comment: Why do you want 3 and 5 but not 4?

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: "the 1st, next to last, and every two between them"... how does this describe: 0,2,3,5,6,8 ?

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving a bit of feedback, were these the answers you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest this approach?

```
def slice_up(array):
    array_list = list(array)
    return sorted(array_list[2:-2:3] + array_list[:-2:3] + [array_list[-2]])
```

The slice notation, e.g. `[2:-2:3]` means that it should start at the `2` index (really the third element, Python indexes start at zero), and go up to, but not including, the 2nd element from the end (`-2`), by threes. I tried the official docs, but it's not coming up immediately, so here's a canonical Stackoverflow Q&A on slicing: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

and to use:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> slice_up(numpy.arange(10))
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
>>> slice_up(numpy.arange(15))
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]
>>> slice_up(numpy.arange(20))
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18]
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I'm still learning many of the different sorting, splitting, joining style tools in python.  I'm a little bit confused about the array_list[2:-2:3]. What does the value in between the colons (:-2:) do as far as picking out values in the array?

Comment: @user3418064 I commented about the slice notation, does that explain it?

Comment: yes, this makes so much more sense and is way less convoluted than what I was trying to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the OP wants what described:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain([x[0]], x[2:-2:2], [x[-2]]))
```

Out[23]: `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

or by the literal example given:

```
def pairs_with_gap(arr):
    seq = iter(arr[2:-2])
    yield arr[0]
    for item in seq:
        yield item
        yield next(seq)
        next(seq)
    yield arr[-2]

print [y for y in pairs_with_gap(x)]
```

Out[26]: `[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]`